# Does Heimdall already know about the prophecy of Ragnarok?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok* Skurge has taken over Heimdall's position and from what it seems like, Loki has specially appointed him so he announces Thor's arrival. Has Loki forcefully removed Heimdall from his rank or had Heimdall known the prophecy of Ragnarok beforehand and thus quit so he could save the people of Asgard behind the scenes?

Comment: Since it's a prophecy, I guess everyone knew it. Plus, Heimdall is all seeing so I think it's not far-fetched to assume he saw it coming.

Comment: In the beginning scene it dint seem like Thor knew much about the prophecy and Sartur had to explain that to him. Even after Thor defeats Sartur he thinks that he has stopped Ragnarok, which may mean he doesn't have a proper understanding of the event.

Comment: I presumed Thor had allowed himself to be captured by Sartur ... precisely because he knew the prophecy, and wanted to prevent it.  He allows Sartur to monologue so he would reveal his plans.

Comment: I may be wrong but I understood that Loki removed Heimdall because, due to his gift of vision, he could see through the illusion of Loki impersonating Odin.

Comment: Ragnarok is a very famous prophecy in Midgard. Why wouldn't it be common knowledge among the Asgardians as well?

Answer (score 4):

In the movie, Skurge tells Thor that Heimdall has been removed by Loki  because of his lack of discipline. Loki has to create some reason in order to remove Heimdall from his position as he was trustworthy to the Kingdom. I think Thor is the only one who knew about the prophecy as he was following the infinity stones.

Heimdall managed to help the people at the right time because he can see the entire universe (and different paths in the Kingdom) with his eyes not because he knew about the prophecy.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The infinity stones don't have anything to do with Ragnarok except that Thor found Surtur while searching for them. Also, Heimdall helping people escape isn't really related, because Hela returning to Asgard is not Ragnarok.

Comment: @KSmarts: I never told  infinity stones have anything to do with the Ragnarok.Thor's vision include  Asgard in flames, as well as images of the Infinity Stones. So while searching for the truth he happens to  find Surthur, thinking that he may be the reason for the destruction of Asgard.Neither Thor or Heimdall could see the possibility of Hela coming to Asgard.